# Libssh2, building library with xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, build, ssh, libssh2

I'm using [this](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS/blob/master/README.md) project to attempt to use the libssh2 library with iOS.  The [readme](https://github.com/x2on/libssh2-for-iOS/blob/master/README.md) does not explain much, however, and I could use some help building the library.

I opened up the example project in xcode, but I am confused about this part of the readme

```
 You can build the libssh2 library with openssl or with libgcrypt!
```

There are several scripts in the project, do I need to run these as build phases in xcode?

Thanks for your help

Comment: so I tried running the build-all script using Xcode Run Script, but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the ./build-all.sh with Terminal